# Mongoose select,populate and save behaving differently on Mac and Windows

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Here's what i did

```
static populateReferralLinks(){
    return Promise.coroutine(function*(){
       let companies = yield Company.find({},'billing referral current_referral_program')
                                        .populate('billing.user','emails name');

       for(let i = 0 ; i < length ; i++){  
         companies[i].referral.is_created = true;
         companies[i].referral.referral_email = companies[i].billing.user.emails[0].email;
         companies[i] = yield companies[i].save();
       }
       return companies;
    }).apply(this)
        .catch((err) => {
            throw err;
        });
}
```

I have a funciton in which i am selecting only 3 fields to go ahead with i.e billing,current_referral_program and referral. 
And populating user using the reference stored in billing.user. 
Now when i call this function then on line

**companies[i].save();**

The following command is shown in the terminal in windows

```
Mongoose: companies.update(
{ _id: ObjectId("58d12e1a588a96311075c45c") }, 
{ '$set': 
   { billing: 
      { configured: false, 
        user: ObjectId("58d12e16588a96311075c45a") }, 
     referral: 
     { is_created: true,  
       referral_email: 'jadon.devesh98@gmail.com', 
     }, 
     updatedAt: new Date("Wed, 22 Mar 2017 12:02:55 GMT") 
   } 
}
)
```

But in Mac's terminal it shows this command

```
Mongoose: companies.update({ _id: ObjectId("58d12e1a588a96311075c45c") }) { '$set': { billing: { configured: false, user: ObjectId("58d12e16588a96311075c45a") }, current_limit: {}, current_usage: {},referral: { is_created: true, referral_email: 'jadon.devesh98@gmail.com'}}, '$unset': { updatedAt: 1 } }
```

Now, I haven't mentioned **current_limit** and **current_usage** to be empty. it's executing fine on windows but on Mac it's setting **current_limit** and **current_usage** empty thus updating my document with empty objects on Mac but not on windows.

It should behave same way on both OS but it is not.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this problem was there in Mongoose 4.5.8 and is resolved in the latest version i.e 4.9.1 
[Check it here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5100)